# PDO Unbuffered queries concern

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have around 300k rows in a table which stores historical data for a chart. I tried and found its memory usage was around 59-62mb (3 months worth of data) using PDO. I have discovered this `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);`, in where I was confused on its drawbacks.

Locking the table while queuing the results, means that I cannot insert/update to the same table right?, if I insert into the table using another computer while my main computer was still queuing for the result what would happen (can't test as I have only 1 laptop and no desktop)?

Comment: Why would you need to "lock the table" if you have SELECT'ed snapshot of query data for the chart? I believe that you would be ok in your scenario, unless I'm missing something? The memory that you mentioned is not really that daunting, unless you have some very old PC's.

Comment: It sounds like you're dropping phrase "locking the table" that you found in documentation, but you haven't cited the docs where you saw that... but it may refer to implicit locks during queries against MyISAM tables (which you are hopefully not using).  This "buffered" option sounds a lot like [`mysql_store_result()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-store-result.html) in the C client API, which may increase the necessary client-side memory, depending on how you are reading the data in your code.  I think more context and background are needed.

Comment: I was concerned on the maximum php memory limit since from 1 query can generate that much MB's... Thanks for the comment.. relieved me from my own thinking burden :) (Paul T.).

Now that u mention MyISAM tables,that would make sense... Thank you :) ( Michael-sqlbot )

It seems I was confused on some random website after reading it regarding unbuffered queries and should have gone straight to the php manual site...